# In Visual Studio 2012 RC, how does one debug javascript IntelliSense extensions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, javascript-intellisense

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes ways in which to extend the JavaScript IntelliSense for Visual Studio 2012 RC. Is there a way to debug, or at least log to some output, any custom extension work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha just found output logging at least by exploration.

```
if(intellisense) {
    intellisense.logMessage("hi!");
}
```

This will write output to "JavaScript Language Service" in output window.

[image: JavaScript Language Service Output]

Now about debugging? :)

Comment: The intellisense object is only available at design-time, so there isn't a way to debug code that relies on it. As you mentioned, the logMessage method is there to help diagnose an extension's behavior. If you want to output the contents of an object, you can use JSON.stringify.

Comment: Thanks @LostInTangent. So you couldn't attach another visual studio to the visual studio instance where you were writing your extension? (Haven't had time to try.) Finally, if you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.